# Send rows selected to php script with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, rows

I have a simple question,

I have a table done with a query result (from php) and I would select multiple rows and send all data from one field to another php script.

For example:

```
    Select   | File name | etc | etc
    -------------------------------
    checkbox1| dog.avi   | etc | etc
    -------------------------------
    checkbox2| cat.avi   | etc | etc

Submit |  Submit2 | Submit3 etc etc
```

Sumbit :  checked rows 'file_name' field to myscript.php
Submit2: delete all checked
Submit3:  checked rows 'file_name' field to myscript2.php

I done this in all rows:

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="file_id" value="'.$valueRow.'">';
```

but after check how can I send multi to my script?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is **client-side** scripting and PHP is **server-side** scripting. You cannot transfer data from PHP to JavaScript without resending a request to the server.

You can create a Form which has **hidden elements**. Upon clicking submit, you can populate and submit this form as a `get` or a `post`. You can retrieve this data on the server side in PHP, and use it in your scripts as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Sending data from a Javascript script (client-side) to a PHP script (client-side) is a technique called AJAX (Asynchronous Javascript and XML) and can be done in Javascript using the [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) object.

To get all the checked checkboxes you can do `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')`. You can then extract the relevant data from these checkboxes which needs to be passed to the PHP script. It's up to you to pass them as a urlencoded string or as a `FormData` object (discussed in the given link) in your AJAX request.